# WMI Queries - use property which is not available in all operating systems

Tags: c#, wmi-query

Propery `Win32_OperatingSystem\OSArchitecture` is available on Windows 7, but is not available on Windows XP. I checked this using WMI Code Generator. How should I change the code below to work on both operating systems (Win XP and Win 7)?

```
ObjectQuery objectQuery = new ObjectQuery("SELECT OSArchitecture FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(objectQuery);
if (searcher.Get().Count == 0) // this line throw exception on Windows XP
    return null;
```

I know that I can catch the exception, but I am looking for a better solution

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
string strOSArchitecture = "";
ObjectQuery objectQuery = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(objectQuery);
ManagementObjectCollection results = searcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject result in results)
{
   foreach (PropertyData property in result.Properties)
   {
      else if (property.Name.Equals("OSArchitecture"))
      {
         strOSArchitecture = result["OSArchitecture"].ToString();
      }
   }
}
```